# 2D Array : Recording an ambiguous '48' after writing to it

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm pretty new to coding and these forums so please be patient with me if I mess up.

Anyway to the question, I'm creating a 2D array to hold past guesses for my game mastermind, as a record, so the user can look back on their previous attempts. I have made a 2D array for the old guesses and it has worked fine from my small "make sure it sorta works" attempts. However, the near exact same for the old feedback (like the you got 2 colours in the right place, 1 in the wrong place and 1 completely wrong colour) it messing up,the number 48 is appearing in it from no-where and for the life, I cant work out why.

Here's my code:

```
const int FEEDBACK_ARRAY_ROWS = 8;
const int FEEDBACK_ARRAY_COL = 3;
int fb_cur_row = 0;
int fb_cur_col = 0;
int Feedback2DArray[FEEDBACK_ARRAY_ROWS][FEEDBACK_ARRAY_COL];
for(int i  = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Feedback2DArray[fb_cur_row][fb_cur_col] = feedback_string[i];
    fb_cur_col++;
    cout << feedback_string[0];
    cout << Feedback2DArray[0][0];
}
fb_cur_row++;
for(int i = 0; i < fb_cur_row; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cout << Feedback2DArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

}

For some reason this "code formatting" doesn't like 1/2 of my code so, luckily this is all I could manage but im pretty sure it has the essential stuff on there. Basically I've for the     cout << feedback_string[0];
    cout << Feedback2DArray[0][0];

As they should output the same thing but they're not. The first line is outputting what it should which is '0' as the counter it is based off is (as they all are) 0. However the send line outputs '48'. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feedback_string` most likely is declared something like the following:

```
char feedback_string[3];
```

In other words, it is an array of `char`. This holds the 3 characters, which are all `'0'`, which has a decimal value of `48` (in ASCII Code). When you perform the assignment below:

```
Feedback2DArray[fb_cur_row][fb_cur_col] = feedback_string[i];
```

You are converting an object of type `char` to an object of type `int`. This is why you see `48` printed, because when you pass an `int` to `cout`, it prints out the value the `int` object holds. When you pass an object of type `char`, it prints out the character representation of that value.

Now, if your goal is to convert the character `'0'` to the actual value `0`, you can use the following trick which takes advantage of how ASCII codes are ordered:

```
Feedback2DArray[fb_cur_row][fb_cur_col] = feedback_string[i] - '0';
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply, I wasn't expecting one so soon. Unfortunately, I have University till 1 (GMT) but after that I'm excited to give it a go. If it works, I <3 you :P